# Mensaje de Confirmación ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

No he podido crear un mensaje de confirmación que sirva para que el usuario vea que los datos han sido guardados correctamente en la base de datos, alguna idea de como hacer este tipo de funcionalidad estoy usando el patrón arquitectónico MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que el mensaje de confirmación quieres mostrarlo con un `alert` de JavaScript. Si este es el caso, deberías definir el mensaje en la `View` y luego, desde el `action`, definir si se muestra o no

Entonces en el `controller` tendrías algo como ser

```
public class HomeController
{

    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        ViewBag.showSuccessAlert = false;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(xxModel model)
    {
        //aqui grabas los datos

        ViewBag.showSuccessAlert = true;

        return View();
    }

}
```

Y en la `view`

```
<html>
    <head>

    if(ViewBag.showSuccessAlert)
    {
        <script>
            alert('Los datos se grabaron corectamente');
        </script>
    }

    </head>

    //resto html

</html>
```

de esta forma, desde el `action` controlas si el código JavaScript que muestra la alerta se mostrará al usuario o no. A donde apunto es que el JavaScript lo tienes definido en la `view`, y desde el `controller` decides si lo muestras.

Answer (score 1):

¿Has provado generar una estructura de resultados? 
Yo generalmente creo un enum de resultados para mis acciones (Tu puedes inventarte las tuyas, esto es un ejemplo pequeño):

```
public enum ResultadoAccion{
    AccionExitosa = 1,
    AccionFallida = 2,
    OperacionInvalida = 3
}
```

Y luego una estructura con el enum para que puedas utilizar su valor (es muy ligero) y en caso de ocurrir algo puedas almacenar lo que sea que ocurra en tu flujo del programa.

```
public struct LogMensaje{
    public ResultadoAccion resultadoAccion;
    public string Suceso;
    public string Detalle;
    public string Causa;
}
```

Por ejemplo, si en algun punto de tu programa caes en un Catch(Exception e):

```
    public LogMensaje MetodoX()
    {
        LogMensaje resultado = new LogMensaje();

        try
        {
            //Codigo
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            resultado.resultadoAccion = ResultadoAccion.AccionFallida;
            resultado.Suceso = e.Message.ToString();
            resultado.Causa = e.Source.ToString();
            resultado.Detalle = e.StackTrace.ToString();
        }

        return resultado;
    }
```

Y cuando hagas llamada de tu metodo, ya sea un Controller o en tu capa de datos, si ocurre algo podras almacenar las causas, no tiene que caer siempre en un Exception, puedes ser creativo y armar una estructura tan grande como quieras. La idea es llevar lo que ocurrio hasta el final no?

```
public void LlamandoMetodoX()
{
    LogMensaje resultado = MetodoX();
}
```

Saludos!